# Outlook appointments being overwritten when created from Excel loop

Tags: excel, outlook, outlook-calendar, vba

I loop through information in an Excel sheet to create appointments in Outlook. It was working when I sent it to my default folder.

I made changes to upload the data to a specific folder (shared by coworkers).

Since then, as I F8 through my code, it saves the appointment for the row being looped through. However, when I go to the next row, the new appointment replaces the old instead of both being saved.

```
Sub ExportToOutlook        

Dim OL as Outlook.Application, Appoint as Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES as Worksheet, _ 
        r as Long, i as Long, WB as ThisWorkook, oFolder as Object, o NameSpace as Namespace

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Export Sheet")
    r = ES.Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Set oNameSpace = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("Insert the ID").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

For i = 2 to r
    With oFolder
        .Subject = ES.Cells(i,1).Value
        .Start = ES.Cells(i,2).Value
        .End = ES.Cells(i,3).Value
        .Location = ES.Cells(i,4).Value
        .AllDayEvent = ES.Cells(i,5).Value
        .Categories = ES.Cells(i,6).Value & " Category"
        .Save
    End With
Next i

Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reupdating the same folder at each row iteration. Try the following:

```
Sub ExportToOutlook        

Dim OL as Outlook.Application, Appoint as Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES as Worksheet, _ 
        r as Long, i as Long, WB as ThisWorkook, oFolder as Object, o NameSpace as Namespace

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Export Sheet")
    r = ES.Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Set oNameSpace = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("Insert the ID")

For i = 2 to r
    Dim appt as MailItem
    Set appt = oFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    With appt
        .Subject = ES.Cells(i,1).Value
        .Start = ES.Cells(i,2).Value
        .End = ES.Cells(i,3).Value
        .Location = ES.Cells(i,4).Value
        .AllDayEvent = ES.Cells(i,5).Value
        .Categories = ES.Cells(i,6).Value & " Category"
        .Save
    End With
Next i

Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim appt as Outlook.AppointmentItem instead of MailItem was the fix! Thankyou! I researched a lot but was unable to finish it off until I started working from your addition.

Answer (score 0):

Dim appt as Outlook.AppointmentItem was the fix for me!

```
Sub ExportToOutlook2()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook, oFolder As Object, oNameSpace As Namespace

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = WB.Sheets("Export Sheet")
    r = ES.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Set oNameSpace = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("00000000579E67EAD9C2C94591E62A3CF21135F801001241364BFDA9AF49A3D3384A976997C50036FCD700060000")

    For i = 2 To r
        Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        Set appt = oFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
        With appt
            .Subject = ES.Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Start = ES.Cells(i, 2).Value
            .End = ES.Cells(i, 3).Value
            .Location = ES.Cells(i, 4).Value
            .AllDayEvent = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
            .Categories = ES.Cells(i, 6).Value
            .Save
        End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing

    End Sub
```